# Permutation of items with quantities

Tags: python, math, permutation

Using python I have to get all the permutations of given subset using python.
I used itertools.permutation but result is a bit different.

Think of a machine and it has a maximum capacity, and we have products can be produced together, and we have to fill the capacity of machine.

Output format is not important, I used a dictionary to describe it. I will make a calculation after getting this combinations.

For example :

```
products = {'x','y','z','a'}
machine_capcacity = 8
#required output as follows:
{'x':5,'y':1,'z':1,'a':1}

{'x':4,'y':2,'z':1,'a':1}
{'x':4,'y':1,'z':2,'a':1}
{'x':4,'y':1,'z':1,'a':2}

{'x':3,'y':3,'z':1,'a':1}
{'x':3,'y':1,'z':3,'a':1}
{'x':3,'y':1,'z':1,'a':3}

{'x':3,'y':2,'z':2,'a':1}
{'x':3,'y':2,'z':1,'a':2}
{'x':3,'y':1,'z':2,'a':2}

{'x':2,'y':4,'z':1,'a':1}
# ...

{'x':6,'y':1,'z':1} # This can't be in results,since need at least 1 element of product
{'x':4,'y':1,'z':1,'a':1} # This can't be in results,since we need to fill the capacity
```

And we dont want repeating elements:

```
{'x':5,'y':1,'z':1,'a':1}
```

and

```
{'a':1,'y':1,'z':1,'x':5}
```

is same thing for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution not relying on `itertools` since it's getting contrived with all the constraints (a product yielding unique results and a minimum of 1 appearance per product):

```
products = {'x','y','z','a'}
machine_capacity=8

def genCap(capacity = machine_capacity,used = 0):
    if used == len(products)-1: yield capacity,None
    else:
        for i in range(1,2+capacity-len(products)+used):
            yield i,genCap(capacity-i,used+1)
def printCaps(caps,current = []):
    if caps is None:
        print(dict(zip(products,current)))
        return
    for i in caps:
        printCaps(i[1],current+[i[0]])

printCaps(genCap())
```

might be optimize-able with tail recursion and the like. Looks almost like `groupby`, but I can't see an easy way to use that.

**For posterity** I leave my old solution - product repeats counts, so filtering it becomes a problem of it's own:

You confused product with permutation. Here is a quick solution using `itertools` product, and the `Counter` collection to create the output you want:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools   import product

products = {'x','y','z','a'}
machine_capacity=8
for x in filter(lambda x: len(x) == len(products),
                map(Counter,product(products,repeat=machine_capacity))): 
    print(dict(x))
```

Note both `product` and `map` are lazy, so they won't be evaluated until you need them. `Counter` provides the output you want, and converting to `dict` cleans it up. Note no order is guaranteed anywhere. The `filter` is used to make sure all your products appear at least once (length of counter equals that of products) - and it is also lazy, so only evaluated when you need it.

Comment: How can I exclude result {'a': 8} or {'a': 7, 'z': 1}, since I need all product be in machine at least once.

Comment: @durdenk Yup - add a filter. Edited.

Comment: {'a': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 1, 'y': 1} and {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1, 'a': 5} are same and I get 336 result for same kind and total of 40000.

Comment: @durdenk seems to difficult with `itertools`. See edit for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to find all possible combinations of the values in `range(machine_capacity)` that both sum to `8` and are unique. Then, the elements in `products` can be mapped to each element in the sublists of the combinations found:

```
products = ['x','y','z','a']
machine_capacity = 8
def combinations(d, current = []):
  if len(current) == len(products):
    yield current
  else:
    for i in range(machine_capacity):
       if sum(current+[i]) <= machine_capacity:
         yield from combinations(d, current+[i])

data = [dict(zip(products, i)) for i in filter(lambda x:sum(x) == 8 and len(x) == len(set(x)), combinations(machine_capacity))]
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 5, 'x': 0, 'z': 2, 'y': 1}, {'a': 4, 'x': 0, 'z': 3, 'y': 1}, {'a': 3, 'x': 0, 'z': 4, 'y': 1}, {'a': 2, 'x': 0, 'z': 5, 'y': 1}, {'a': 5, 'x': 0, 'z': 1, 'y': 2}, {'a': 1, 'x': 0, 'z': 5, 'y': 2}, {'a': 4, 'x': 0, 'z': 1, 'y': 3}, {'a': 1, 'x': 0, 'z': 4, 'y': 3}, {'a': 3, 'x': 0, 'z': 1, 'y': 4}, {'a': 1, 'x': 0, 'z': 3, 'y': 4}, {'a': 2, 'x': 0, 'z': 1, 'y': 5}, {'a': 1, 'x': 0, 'z': 2, 'y': 5}, {'a': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 2, 'y': 0}, {'a': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'y': 0}, {'a': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 4, 'y': 0}, {'a': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 5, 'y': 0}, {'a': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 0, 'y': 2}, {'a': 0, 'x': 1, 'z': 5, 'y': 2}, {'a': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 0, 'y': 3}, {'a': 0, 'x': 1, 'z': 4, 'y': 3}, {'a': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 0, 'y': 4}, {'a': 0, 'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'y': 4}, {'a': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 0, 'y': 5}, {'a': 0, 'x': 1, 'z': 2, 'y': 5}, {'a': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 1, 'y': 0}, {'a': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 5, 'y': 0}, {'a': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 0, 'y': 1}, {'a': 0, 'x': 2, 'z': 5, 'y': 1}, {'a': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 0, 'y': 5}, {'a': 0, 'x': 2, 'z': 1, 'y': 5}, {'a': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 1, 'y': 0}, {'a': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 4, 'y': 0}, {'a': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 0, 'y': 1}, {'a': 0, 'x': 3, 'z': 4, 'y': 1}, {'a': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 0, 'y': 4}, {'a': 0, 'x': 3, 'z': 1, 'y': 4}, {'a': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 1, 'y': 0}, {'a': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 3, 'y': 0}, {'a': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 0, 'y': 1}, {'a': 0, 'x': 4, 'z': 3, 'y': 1}, {'a': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 0, 'y': 3}, {'a': 0, 'x': 4, 'z': 1, 'y': 3}, {'a': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 1, 'y': 0}, {'a': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 2, 'y': 0}, {'a': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 0, 'y': 1}, {'a': 0, 'x': 5, 'z': 2, 'y': 1}, {'a': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 0, 'y': 2}, {'a': 0, 'x': 5, 'z': 1, 'y': 2}]
```

Comment: x:sum(x) == 8 , I think this is x:sum(x) == machine_capacity,?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get correct output except that there are {'y': 1, 'x': 0, 'z': 2, 'a': 3} , which is a zero element. And If I set machine_capacity to 5 , I get no output at all.